# How to pivot multiple factors while retaining other long data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot-table, tidyr, data-wrangling

Lets say I have this dataset:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Create Data ####
df <- data.frame(city = c("rural","urban","rural","urban","rural"),
                 smog = c("high","low","high","low","high"),
                 x1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 x2 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 y2 = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Which looks like this:

```
  city smog x1 x2 y1 y2
1 rural high  1  1  1  1
2 urban  low  2  2  2  2
3 rural high  3  3  3  3
4 urban  low  4  4  4  4
5 rural high  5  5  5  5
```

Pivoting this data into long format isn't difficult if I am using one variable. However, I am trying to pivot the x and y variables into one column each while retaining the city and smog variables within the same data. The data I am looking at currently has many variables that need to be converted to long format and many that need to remain wide. My best guess was this:

```
#### Pivot Data ####
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains(c("x","y")),
               names_to = c("x.items", "y.items"),
               values_to = "value")
```

As well as this:

```
#### Pivot Data Version 2 ####
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains(c("x","y")),
               names_to = c("x.items", "y.items"),
               values_to = c("value.x", "value.y"))
```

But this doesn't seem to work in either case. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `names_to` with `.value` and define the pattern in `names_pattern` (here, the first group is either an `x` or a `y`, and the second group is the digit). The name of the column is given by the name of the group in the same position than `.value` (here, first one).

Note that `contains(c("x", "y"))` includes `"city"`, so better use `matches` or negation (what I'm doing here).

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -c("city", "smog"),
               names_to = c(".value", "n"),
               names_pattern = "(x|y)(\\d)")
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   city  smog  n         x     y
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 rural high  1         1     1
 2 rural high  2         1     1
 3 urban low   1         2     2
 4 urban low   2         2     2
 5 rural high  1         3     3
 6 rural high  2         3     3
 7 urban low   1         4     4
 8 urban low   2         4     4
 9 rural high  1         5     5
10 rural high  2         5     5
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer! This is very close to what I need. Since there are many long values in my dataset, would using `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -everything(),  names_to = c(".value", "n"), names_pattern = "(x|y)(\\d)")` work? I'm assuming this wouldn't but I'm not sure what the alternative is.

Comment: No, it wouldn't (since then you are selecting 0 variables). But to avoid negative selection, you can do something like `starts_with(c("x", "y"))`